# Send Multiple Posts At A Time

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest

I am using a SQL Query to select data from my database and storing the returned results in a `Dictionary<string, string>` I then use a `foreach` loop and `Server.UrlEncode` to create a `Querystring` like such

```
foreach (var onetwo in privatedictionary) 
    dataToPost = onetwo.Key+"="+Server.UrlEncode(onetwo.Value)+"&";
```

then once the data has been compiled into `dataToPost` I use `HttpWebRequest` to send the data

```
HttpWebRequest wbrq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("www.sitetohit.com");
{
  using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(wbrq.GetRequestStream()))
  {
    sw.Write(dataToPost);
  }
}
```

What is a way using `Visual Studio 2015` to send multiple Posts at once?

Comment: You could use threads for parallel operations.

Comment: @TeodorIvanov - at which portion would I add in a `Parallel.For`?  My dictionary can only hold one value at a time, so would I need to create multiple dictionaries?  Or get a count of how many possible records the SQL Query could return and use the `Parallel.For` on that notion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways, the best that I experienced are bellows:

```
Parallel.ForEach(privatedictionary, (dataToPost) =>
        {
            HttpWebRequest wbrq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("www.sitetohit.com");
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(wbrq.GetRequestStream()))
                {
                    sw.Write(dataToPost);
                }
            }
        });
```

Or:

```
foreach (var dataToPost in privatedictionary)
        {
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                Foo foo = new Foo();
                await foo.BarAsync(dataToPost);
            });
        }

  //Asynchronous Handling
  public class Foo
{
    public async Task BarAsync(string dataToPost)
    {
        HttpWebRequest wbrq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("www.sitetohit.com");
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(wbrq.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                await sw.WriteAsync(dataToPost);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can use this:

```
Parallel.ForEach(privatedictionary, (onetwo) =>
        {
            var dataToPost = onetwo.Key + "=" + Server.UrlEncode(onetwo.Value) + "&";
            HttpWebRequest wbrq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("www.sitetohit.com");
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(wbrq.GetRequestStream()))
                {
                    sw.Write(dataToPost);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: a dictionary can not have duplicate values how can I overcome that so that I can return multiple result sets from my database?

Comment: You can loop through the dictionary and build the **dataToPost** inside the loop body.

Comment: Maybe I am unable to fathom what you are trying to relay to me, all I see is if the dictionary can only hold 1 value at at time, I can't loop 1 value...

Comment: If you have one value at a time you don't need a dictionary. Instead, you need to have two variables and store key and value inside them. Otherwise, you have a problem with your dictionary while storing the value into it.